# ¿Cómo mapear un array de objetos en React.js?

Tags: javascript, array, reactjs

Tengo el siguiente arreglo de objetos:

```
[
  {
  "0":
  {
  "modulos":[{"video1":"https"}],
  "detalle_curso":"DETALLE CURSO AQUI",
  "id":3,
  "nombre":"Vender Online",
  "categoria":"ventas",
  "precio":100
  }
},
  {
  "0":
  {
  "categoria":"ventas",
  "cantidad_modulos":6,
  "modulos":[{"video1":"https"}],
  "detalle_curso":"DETALLE CURSO POTENCIA TU NEGOCIO AQUI",
  "nombre":"Potencia tu negocio",
  "precio":100,
  "id":4
},
  "1":
  {
  "id":2,
  "nombre":"Trading Avanzado",
  "precio":150,
  "detalle_curso":"DETALLE TRADING AVANZADO AQUI",
  "cantidad_modulos":10,
  "modulos":[{"video1":"https"}],
  "categoria":"trading"
},
  "2":
  {
  "id":1,
  "modulos":[{"video1":"https"}],
  "nombre":"Trading Básico",
  "detalle_curso":"TEXTO DETALLE CURSO AQUÍ",
  "precio":100,
  "cantidad_modulos":5,
  "categoria":"trading"
  }
 }
]
```

Y lo que yo quisiera es poder acceder sólo a los objetos para poder mapearlos, que en este caso están separados en un arreglo de longitud = 2.
Estaba haciendo lo siguiente:

```
{misCursos.map((cursos) => (
   <DetallesCursos key={id} cursos={cursos} />
))}
```

Pero esto no accedía a los objetos, sino a los elementos del arreglo de longitud = 2, ¿cómo podría hacer?

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con "tamaño = 2"?

Comment: @Desarrollos-Web-Urquiza  Me refiero a la longitud, en este caso tiene 2 y está imprimiendo 2 veces pero no llega a mostrar lo que contiene dentro (que son los objetos)

Comment: No entiendo, ¿osea que querés mostrar los módulos? O qué es lo que quieres hacer?

Comment: Poniendo en contexto. el usuario en "Mis cursos" tendría que tener todos los cursos, que son los objetos que tiene cada elemento del array . Al mapearlo me muestra de manera errónea ya que muestra los elementos 0 y 1 pero no el contenido (que son los objetos)

Comment: Ese problema te sucede porque tienes anidado el objeto que tiene la información a la que quieres acceder dentro de la propiedad de otro objeto. Podría haber varias soluciones, pero una de ellas podría ser usar el [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys). Por ejemplo, dentro del ciclo que genera el `.map`, lo usas así: `cursos[Object.keys(cursos)[0]]`. De esa forma accederás a la primera propiedad de los objetos que estás mapeando independientemente del nombre que tenga dicha propiedad.